# nautilus can't delete file on NFS server

Tags: permissions, nautilus, nfs

I have a mount to NFS share. If I use a terminal and rm the file (with my user) it works with no issue. I am able to delete files. However if I try to use Nautilus to navigate to the DIR and delete the file it wont work. If I right click on the file the delete option is grayed out. If it was a permission issue how would I be able to delete the file from the terminal?

EDIT: I am using a Synology NAS as my NFS server. I can't create, copy or paste anything with Nautilus. But again from the Linux terminal (with the same user) I have no issue. It definitely seems like a permissions issue but if it was one, why would it work from the terminal but not Nautilus.

Comment: So, "Move to trash" is grayed out?  I have an NFS mount here but I am unable to see what you are seeing.  On your server with your NFS mount, what is the output of `cat /etc/exports`?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1368696/edit) your question and add more details.  If you can, also add a screenshot showing that Nautilus has that option grayed out.

Comment: This is nfs3  or nfs4  share ?

Comment: @pasmanpasmański Why would that matter to Nautilus? I didn't check but I will now (I will force v3 and then v4 and test the difference.

Comment: Sounds like you might have found a bug in Nautilus.  Try installing maybe some other file managers like Nemo, Thunar, xfe, etc and see if you can duplicate the same as Nautilus.